# Update Mongo Document with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to update an existing mongodb document by its ID with pymongo(version 3.0.3). However nothing gets updated with my python code. Does anyone know why..?

Here is the mongodb script I want to run and this works fine from a mongo client, Robomongo.

```
db.mycollection.update(
  { '_id': ObjectId("55d49338b9796c337c894df3") },
  { $set: { "details.model": "14Q22" } },
  upsert=false
  )
```

However this python code does not work.

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("1.1.1.1", 27017)
db = client.mydb

db.mycollection.update(
  { '_id': "55d49338b9796c337c894df3" },
  { '$set': { "details.model": "14Q22" } },
  upsert=False
  )
```

It returns

```
{u'n': 0, u'nModified': 0, u'ok': 1, 'updatedExisting': False}
```

Comment: perhaps, you can try update_one? http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one

Comment: update_one added a new document even though this id already exists. Whereas the first mongo script properly adds details.model. Do I have to specify the mongodb id in a different way?

Comment: `client["mydb"]["mycollection"].update({ '_id': "55d49338b9796c337c894df3" },
  { '$set': { "details.model": "14Q22" } },
  upsert=False)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you have to specify an `ObjectId` instance as follows:

```py
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
db.mycollection.update({'_id': ObjectId("55d49338b9796c337c894df3")},  {'$set': {"details.model": "14Q22"}})
```

- also notice that `mycollection.update`, although it works, is deprecated
  due to introduction of new CRUD operations, better use
  `mycollection.update_one` or `mycollection.find_one_and_update`

Comment: Ah, that was my guess but did not know how to do it. Also appreciate your deprecation feedback. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ek-ok you are welcome:-) 
also...  probably you have the ObjectId as returned by the insert or find operation, in that case you don't have to instantiate a new one.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: TypeError
Exception Value: 
Object of type 'ObjectId' is not JSON serializable